# Retrieve data from 3 different tables

Tags: sql

I have three tables named *areadetails*, *schooldetails* and *childdetails* and iI want to retrieve the data from 3 tables (see attached picture)

The first three columns has dropdown and they have *id* related and last five columns have the same table name *childdetails*.

Can anyone help me write the sql query to get the specific details from the table. Any help would be great.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service Nor is it a substitute for basic reading about how to do things like selects and joins. Show what you have tried so far. People also shouldn't have to guess about the data, so show the schema and examples of data and desired output, and tag which implementation of SQL you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add a schema of a tables, it would be great to help you,

still u can follow the below syntax on this,

```
SELECT A.*, B.*, C.* 
FROM Table1 A INNER JOIN Table2 B ON A.Id = B.AId
INNER JOIN Table3 C ON A.Id = C.AId
```

If you need more details provide us the schema and expected result

Comment: how can i send the screenshots here

Comment: i think you can add it in your main post only

Comment: @kumaranindo92: do **not** add table definitions as screen shots. [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52530002/edit) your question and add them as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) do not post code or additional information as comments. That's what the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52530002/edit) below your question is for